# Oracle select * from all_sequences too slow

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My project uses Hibernate and I wanted to increase startup time(currently 1.5 minutes), so I inspected what's happening on startup. During `SessionFactory` initialization, one of the queries issued is:

```
select * from all_sequences;
```

It takes close to a minute! The same query from Oracle SQL Developer takes similar amount of time.
Total records returned are 102.

There are other queries which run normally(one digit ms response time)

Why is it so slow?

Comment: As that's a built-in view it might be something you need to raise with Oracle. You could run the same in SQL\*Plus to rule out a JDBC issue but that seems unlikely anyway. I've occasionally seen similar issues with those views but with no pattern I can recall; possible rebooting the DB might help but bit of a hammer approach! Just curious - which DB version and patch level is this? And do you see the same thing with `user_` and `dba_` views?

Comment: Thanks. It's 18.3.0. I forgot to mention the instance is in a Docker container. This one https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gather optimizer statistics for the data dictionary and fixed objects:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
    dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
end;
/
```

Oracle needs good statistics for objects in order to build good execution plans.  There are many mechanisms for gathering statistics for our custom objects, but occasionally we also need to gather statistics for system objects.  (Although I'm surprised this is necessary right out of the box.  Normally these problems only happen after extreme changes, like creating a million new sequences.)

If gathering optimizer statistics doesn't help, try generating an execution plan with the below steps, and posting the result in the question.

```
--Run the query:
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from all_sequences;

--Find the SQL_ID:
select * from gv$sql where sql_text like '%gather_plan_statistics%';

--Generate the execution plan, with estimated and actual results.
select *
from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '9wgbmhhrf0bwr', format=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, Jon! Gathering optimizer statistics fixed it(though still not clear what's happening). Do I have to run it every time Oracle is started? The problem was occurring when query was run from custom users, i.e. not when I was logged in as SYSTEM

Comment: @isah You only need to run it once.

Comment: is it possible to customize inititalization queries